# Merge selected values MySQL from every other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem and I have no solution.

I have embedded systems (which have unique site_id:s) reporting temperatures with a certain periodicity to MYSQL server.
Sometimes the outside temperatures T00 is corrupt (this I will detect manually)in which case I want to replace T00 from site_id 1 with T00 from site_id 2.

I want to use the temperature nearest in time which I can find by looking at the calculated_time_stamp. There will always be a valid temperature from site_id 2 within the next or previous 23 minutes. I want to do this for typically 5000 records at the time.

If I select site_id 1 and 2 the output would look like:

```
Site_id calculated_time_stamp  T00  T01   T02  
   1    2017-02-12 21:00:00    25   32.0  28.2  
   2    2017-02-12 21:15:00    2.3  31.0  29.1  
   1    2017-02-12 21:23:43    25   32.3  28.0  
   2    2017-02-12 21:38:42    2.4  33.3  28.1
```

After I perform some SQL swap magic that I can't figure out on my own I want it to look like this:

```
 Site_id    calculated_time_stamp   T00  T01   T02  
       1    2017-02-12 21:00:00     2.3  32.0  28.2  
       2    2017-02-12 21:15:00     2.3  31.0  29.1  
       1    2017-02-12 21:23:43     2.4  32.3  28.0  
       2    2017-02-12 21:38:42     2.4  33.3  28.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show sample input and output.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  If two rows are within, say, X seconds of each other, which `T00` value do you use?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for for respons. I have now tried to describe it in another way. I want to use the T00 from the previuus or next but from a different site_id.

Comment: Ideas anyone?  I have tried what Karen suggested but I guess it ends up in some sort of circle reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name a
SET a.t00 =
  (SELECT b.t00 FROM table_name b 
     WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(a. calculated_time_stamp, b. calculated_time_stamp)) < 23*60
     AND b.site_id=2)
WHERE a.site_id=1
```

Try using something like this

Comment: Thanks Karan. I tried this but I get the following error:
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause